# how can read the value dynamically from array of objects and count it?

Tags: c#, arrays

[image]

provider is my doctor and every doctor has patient test now I want to count unique test name and its reading of very test type. test name is repeating but I want to unique and its reading count

```
        var criticalReading = new ProviderBL().GetCriticalReadingByProvider(userid);
        CriticalReadingListViewModel obj = new CriticalReadingListViewModel();
        int D = 0;
        int S = 0;
        int u = 0;
        foreach (var item in criticalReading)
        {

            if (item.AttributeName == "Systolic")
            {
                obj.Dcounter = S;
                S++;
            }
            else if (item.AttributeName == "Diastolic")
            {
                obj.Scounter = D;
                D++;
            }
            else
            {
                u++;
            }

        }
```

Comment: the S++ and D++ is supposed to come before obj.Dcounter = S;  and obj.Scounter = D; respectively. whats saving the u++ (was expecting a obj.Ucounter = u;)

Comment: The problem isn't explicit, and no error given!!

Comment: Tip: the question is not related to asp.net, this is c# only, so no need to mention that. Also, when you describe the issue, nobody cars about doctors, cars, etc. Speak object - array, items, dependencies. We don't need your business rules

Comment: how can cant to reading count and update into previous object and set into viewbag then show on view?ViewBag.CriticalReadings = criticalReading;

Comment: You may elaborate on what "dynamically" means. This seems like an XY problem. Your counting should be okay but something bothers you. Do you want to "dynamically" update your count while counting?

Comment: yes, it would show dynamical test name and its reading count with all reaming tables fileds names one time. but reading count and test name unique

Comment: var d = tests.GroupBy(k => k.AttributeName, v => v.Reading).ToDictionary(g =>g.Key, g=>g.ToList());  in this way its showing dynamically but I need all remaining fileds name also but count on these two fileds.

Answer (score 2):

From what I see in your code, this may be the answer

```cs
var systolicCount = array.Count(item => item.AttributeName == "Systolic");
var diastolicCount = array.Count(item => item.AttributeName == "Diastolic");
```

These are LINQ lambda methods that will count number of items having certain attribute

Comment: Thank you for your information,  I need these test name count dynamically like group by query by testID and all remaining names

Comment: @UmarFaraz As I pointed out, this is all I can get from our code. Should you improve your question, we can improve answers. It is totally not clear, what **"dynamically"** means to you? Your question has button "Edit" - use it.

Comment: sure, actually I want to read the test name and count its value dynamically, like groupby attributename and reading then count its value each test has how many reading value. group by would implement on attribute name and reading and other table name also wold be show in select.

Answer (score 0):

To uniquely count something and retain the original data too, you can use a `Dictionary<string, List<int>>`

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
foreach(Test t in tests)
{
  if(!d.ContainsKey(t.AttributeName))
    d[t.AttributeName] = new List<int>();

  d[t.AttributeName].Add(t.Reading);
}
```

You now have a dictionary with one entry per test attribute name. Each dictionary entry value is a list of ints that are the readings. Thus `d.Count` is the number of unique tests

If you want more information out of the test it might be better to retain the whole test object in the dictionary value rather than just the Reading

You can also use LINQ to create such a dictionary:

```
var d = tests.GroupBy(k => k.AttributeName, v => v.Reading).ToDictionary(g =>g.Key, g=>g.ToList());
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211064/discussion-on-answer-by-caius-jard-how-can-read-the-value-dynamically-from-array).